# How to work properly with UIView and drawRect() to customize it in the playground?

Tags: swift, xcode7

Why in playground function drawRect() doesn't work when I want to override it and show view?
I try to do this:

```
class CustomView: UIView {
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        //some code to change self properties
    }
}
let rect = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 300.0, height: 300.0)
let view = CustomView(frame: rect)
view
```

Then I try to change some properties (for example: backgroundColor). But they aren't applied.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I discovered the next case:

To apply set backgroundColor in drawRect I need to call this:

```
view.setNeedsDisplay()
```

BUT: From documentation:

> For example, you do not need to override this method if your view just
>   displays a background color or if your view sets its content directly
>   using the underlying layer object.